# How to change directory within Ubuntu WSL in Windows format?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cd

I have installed Cygwin on Windows. To change dir in Cygwin could be done in 2 ways:

**In Unix format:**

```
cd /cygdrive/path/to/folder/
```

**In Windows format (surrounded by double quotes):**

```
cd "C:\Path\To\Folder\"
```

Is there a way to change dir in Ubuntu WSL like can be done on Cygwin, using Windows format?

I get this error when trying on Ubuntu:

```
$ cd "C:\Path\To\Folder"
-bash: cd: C:\Path\To\Folder\: No such file or directory
$ cd "C:\Path\To\Folder\"
>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. In order to access Windows files from WSL you need to visualize an Ubuntu VM that has mounted NTFS drives, so access needs to be using `/mnt/c/...` or `/mnt/d/...` etc.

You need to use forward slashes as shown, since backward slashes (`\`) will be interpreted as escape characters within WSL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cahit. It would be nice to know who and why someone does a downvote.

Answer (score 8):

WSL stores your Windows drives in the /mnt folder, with the name of the drive as a subfolder. For example your C:\ drive will be present at /mnt/c/ for you to use.

Keeping this in mind, you can swap to your specific folder like so:

cd /mnt/d
cd /mnt/e/username/folder1/folder2

Answer (score 4):

copied from sincostan, define this function in your .bashrc:

```
cdw() { local d=`wslpath "$1"`; cd "$d"; }
```

then , use like this:

```
cdw 'E:\username\folder1\folder2'
```

it seems there is no way to avoid inputing the quote marks.

Answer (score 2):

One more alternative, without defining the function, e.g. for temporary use:

```
cd `wslpath 'E:\example\path'`
```

Note that you need both backtick surrounding the `wslpath` command and its parameter, and single quotes surrounding the windows path, to avoid unintentional escaping of backslashes.